# How can we load the Relationship in Laravel with sum of different column?

Tags: laravel, relationship, has-many

I'm trying to get the sum of three different columns using Laravel query builder.
I want to calculate the sum of 3 subjects. for example, Student table contains information and record table have marks details with `hasmany` relationship.

```
public function getrecord()
{
    $student = Student::with('Record')->get();

    return $this->success($student);
}
```

This is the output I am getting:
[image: Image shows the student_id exist in the record table]

```
// Query working for sum but not loading the Relationship (object details).
$student = Student::addSelect([
    'total_marks' => record::wherecolumn('student_id', 'student.id')
        ->selectRaw('sum(Math+Eng+Urdu) as total_marks')
])->get();
```

Output:
[image: Getting sum but not details of object see the image]

Comment: Do not use images to paste code or outputs, as the image will eventually go down and the question will be unusable. Please, copy-paste the output as code and paste it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geniune question: how do you expect this code to load the relationship?

```php
$student = Student::addSelect([
    'total_marks' => Record::whereColumn('student_id', 'student.id')
        ->selectRaw('SUM(Math + Eng + Urdu) AS total_marks')
])->get();
```

You are missing the `with` to eager load the relationship:

```php
$student = Student::with('Record')
    ->addSelect([
        'total_marks' => record::wherecolumn('student_id', 'student.id')
            ->selectRaw('sum(Math+Eng+Urdu) as total_marks')
    ])
    ->get();
```

Comment: I'm trying to add with statement after the addselect. Exhausted!!!

Comment: @ArbazKhalid what issues are you having? I do not recall if it must go before or after `addSelect`, but it should be fine either way, it does not matter where it is placed/when it is called. Only matters that it is called before `->get()`

Comment: problem is solved by your solution :) . but matters is that it throws error when i try to add with() after addselect. Btw i solved my query. really helpfull.

Comment: Oh okay, nice to see that it was solved! could you mark my answer as correct, please?